# Does Logstash has a limit size for each event-message?

Tags: logstash

I am implementing a monitoring tool on servers of my company service. To do that, I am using logstash. Our applications send their logs via a log4net udp appender to logstash (input udp) and then logstash grok them, and send them to elasticsearch. When I display my logs in kibana, I see that some logs are truncated, the last main part is missing (for big logs). So my question is, does Logstash has a size limit for each message-event received. If yes, is it possible to increase the size. I need all my logs and none of them truncated.

Answer (score 4):

**Update for 2021**:

The maximum size is set by the `buffer_size` parameter in the UDP input. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-udp.html#plugins-inputs-udp-buffer_size

The default buffer size is:

- 65536 bytes on Logstash >= 5.1
- 8192 bytes on Logstash >= 2.0
- 4096 bytes on older versions.

A UDP datagram is limited to 65535 bytes, the length header being 16 bits.

Answer (score 3):

For the udp case, I think that I have found the solution :
-increase the buffer_size parameter in udp.rb file.

I cannot test it now, but I will tell you if it works.

Comment: You can just specific at the configuration. No need to modify the udp.rb. Please check the buffer_size in http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/udp

Comment: Setting the buffer_size in the input filter does NOT work in Logstash v5.2.

Answer (score 2):

I have test it with Logstash 1.4.0 and Logstash 1.3.3. 
I found that the `maximum size of an event is 4095`!

So, If your logs have larger than this size, maybe you have to split it to multiple event at the time you send the logs to logstash.

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer. But I have some basic questions : What is the unit of 4095? How to calculate the size of my message to know if it reaches 4095(unit)?

Comment: I think it is probably 4096, 4KB. I try it with input over 4096 character and then the message only output 4095 character. Maybe the last byte is '\n'

Comment: ok, for my case, all the messages with caracters count less than 8551 appears in integrality. For the others, messages are truncated at the 8551th caracter.

Comment: Can you tell how/where you found this information ?

Answer (score 2):

*Logstash's* property **buffer_size** is by default set to **8192**. That's why messages sent over *UDP* to *Logstash* are truncated at **8192th** symbol.

Try increasing UDP **buffer_size** in Logstash.

**References**:

- https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/1505
- https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/2111
- http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/udp#buffer_size *(may be outdated, check documentation version)*