# Processing large json's using logstash - Not working and not printing any error

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I started using `logstash` (**on windows**) when my main cause of use will be passing `logstash` a large json (10 mb), filtering the `json` somehow and write it out to `elastic search`.

As for now, I don't really care about the `json` filtering (I will care after I'll get this to work). I wan't the file to pass through `logstash` and get to my `elastic search`.

The client who feeds `logstash` uses a `tcp` connection.

My `logstash` simple configuration file looks like:

```
input
{
    tcp
    {
        port=>7788
        codec=>"json"
    }
}

output
{
    elasticsearch
    {
        hosts=>"localhost:9200"
        codec=>"json"
    }
    stdout
    {
        codec=>rubydebug
    }
}
```

This **does work** for me on small `json` inputs like:

```
{"foo":"bar", "bar": "foo"}
```

I see the `logstash` working and passing the data to `elastic search` and 
**everything's ok**.

Also, when using the default codec ("text") it worked, but not as expected.

My problem starts when the inputs are large `jsons`.

Assuming I have a 10 mb `json` - what do I need to do with it so `logstash` will be able to handle it over `tcp` as a `json`? Should the file be indented or not? What encoding should I use before I convert it into bytes? What codec\settings should my logstash have?

BTW, when I use curl and through the large `json` directly to elastic search - it works - So there are no problems with the `json`.

Is there any way I can get some better tracing or at least know why I fail?

Comment: How the world  single line of logger becomes more than 10mb of data. Just wondering

Comment: My log file is the a trace output (json) of a rule engine's request. I currently want to handle the tracing on the client's end and not on the rule engine's end. That's the next step :).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24606772/4506140

Comment: @CrazyNinja - I'm not sure that's accurate. I just checked a 10K json (key value) and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem wasn't the length but the lack of a newline - So all I needed to do was to add a newline to my log files.

BTW, there is **no** 4K length limit - At least not when working with TCP.